# Выполнения кода не в расширении а в отрытой вкладке

Tags: javascript, extension

Хочу сделать расширение для браузера, добавляющее кнопку в div. Пытался сделать, но на сколько я понял, он выполняет код в расширении, а не на странице.

Как сделать, что-бы код добавился на страницу, а не в расширение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы про расширение для chrome, то вам необходимо написать [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).

Сейчас, видимо, вы все пишете в [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app#two)

Вот пример, где `document` это ссылка на `window.document`текущей страницы

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
});
```